# Is the Amazon Dash Wand open to custom skills in Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Can custom Alexa skills use the Amazon Dash Wand either through open APIs or some other integration endpoint?

Comment: I just got my Dash Wand in the mail.
I tried the AskGoogle custom skill, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wand can use Alexa voice skills by using the button to trigger the microphone (no wakeword needed). Unfortunately, there is no access in the current API to access the barcode scanner and it doesn't support some services such as music streaming.